# must have class/struct/union

Tags: visual-c++

Hello I am working on an assignment for school, but I am running into a few problems, I am a beginner in c++ and not real familiar with it. I really appreciate the help I have been given so far but I am still getting errors on lines 31-35.

```
error C2228: left of '.substr' must have class/struct/union

error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
```

Here is my assignment
 A parking garage charges a $2.00 minimum fee to park for up to three hours. The garage charges an additional $0.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in excess of three hours. The maximum charge for
any given 24-hour period is $10.00. People who park their cars for longer than 24 hours will pay $8.00 per day.
Write a program that calculates and prints the parking charges. The inputs to your program are the date and time when a car enters the parking garage, and the date and time when the same car leaves the parking garage. Both inputs are in the format of
`YY/MM/DD hh:mm`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int dateStr;
int parseDate( std::string dateStr );

int main ()

{
int enter_date;
int enter_time;
int exit_date;
int exit_time;
cout << "Please enter the date and time the car is entering "<< endl
    << "the parking garage in the following format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm"<< endl;
 cin >> enter_date >> enter_time;


cout<< "Please enter the date and time the car is exiting "<< endl
    << "the parking garage in the following format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm"<< endl;
cin >> exit_date >> exit_time;

{
    // Format: YY/MM/DD hh:mm
    int year  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 0, 2 ).c_str() );
    int month = atoi( dateStr.substr( 3, 2 ).c_str() );
    int day   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 6, 2 ).c_str() );
    int hour  = atoi( dateStr.substr( 9, 2 ).c_str() );
    int min   = atoi( dateStr.substr( 12, 2 ).c_str() );

    // Now calculate no. of mins and return this
    int totalMins = 0;
    totalMins += ( year * 365 * 24 * 60 ); // Warning: may not be accurate enough
    totalMins += ( month * 30 * 24 * 60 ); // in terms of leap years and the fact
    totalMins += ( day * 24 * 60 );        // that some months have 31 days
    totalMins += ( hour * 60 );
    totalMins += ( min );

    return totalMins;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `dateStr` as an `int`.  Is it supposed to be a string?  You should probably initialize it, too.

Comment: I am really not sure... I tried changing it to a string but it did not seem to help. maybe I did it wrong? Also I thought I did initialize it by putting int in front of it, is that wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to basics.  Try making a smaller program work, and then build up to your assignment.

Comment: I have been doing this for less than a month, totally thought this was "the basics"....  so I changed it to a string like you said, however I am now getting this error...  This application has requested the Run-time to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.